# Insert String array as label content in datagrid row through radio button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have written some code for inserting a label at runtime that has its content set to a string array into a datagrid row. All of this will initiate when certain radio buttons are checked. The code is working perfectly fine, but I need to improve this code as I am learning C#, WPF and datagrid. I know there can be a certain way to improve this code. This code will be a nightmare when there are 50 radio buttons. Can it be improved?

**XAML Code:**

```xaml
<Grid>
<RadioButton x:Name="rb_1" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="1" />
<RadioButton x:Name="rb_2" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="1"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rb_3" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="1"  />
<RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="2" />
<RadioButton x:Name="rb_4" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="2"/>
<RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="2" />
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="713,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="549,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="253" Width="399" />
<RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,226,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="3" />
<RadioButton x:Name="rb_6" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,246,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="3"/>
<RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="3" />
<RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,298,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="4" />
<RadioButton x:Name="rb_8" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,318,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="4"/>
<RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,338,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="4" />
```

**Code Behind:**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    DataTable dt;
    DataRow dr;
    string[] str = new string[4];
    int location = 0;
    int count = 0;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new DataTable("emp");
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Factors", typeof(string));
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Non_Compliant", typeof(string));

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

        datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (count >= 1)
        {
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            dt.Clear();
        }

        str[0] = "Load Path1";
        str[1] = "Load Path2";
        str[2] = "Load Path3";
        str[3] = "Load Path4";
        int j = 0;

        if (rb_2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Height = 28;
            label.Width = 100;
            label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label.Content = str[j];
            dr[k] = label.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            location += 34;

        }
        if (rb_4.IsChecked == true)
        {
            j = 1;
            int k = 0;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Height = 28;
            label.Width = 100;
            label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label.Content = str[j];
            dr[k] = label.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            location += 34;

        }
        if (rb_6.IsChecked == true)
        {
            j = 2;
            int k = 0;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Height = 28;
            label.Width = 100;
            label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label.Content = str[j];
            dr[k] = label.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            location += 34;

        }
        if (rb_8.IsChecked == true)
        {
            j = 3;
            int k = 0;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Height = 28;
            label.Width = 100;
            label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label.Content = str[j];
            dr[k] = label.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            location += 34;
        }
        count++;

    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, Vanadium90. Hope you get some fine answers.

Comment: looking forward :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
DataTable dt;
DataRow dr;
string[] str = new string[4];
int location = 0;
int count = 0;
```

Always use explicit [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

Also, do any of those fields really need to be global?

---

Now, the real problem is that you don't follow [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx). A lot of my other issues follow from that.

For instance:

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="713,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
```

You shouldn't use the Click of a button; instead you should [bind it to a command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314828/bind-command-in-wpf-using-mvvm).

You also use the name of your `DataGrid` in your code behind, `datagrid_`. That is a meaningless name that doesn't follow any naming guideline. Quite frankly, I don't think I've used the `Name` of a `XAML` object more than a handful of times in the years I did Silverlight development: whenever possible you should [bind to a source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320.aspx).

I also see a lot of `Margin` properties being used in very specific ways. I would urge you to look into the [various layout possibilities of XAML](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html) and apply those. Don't work pixel-perfect, it's pointless IMHO and just a maintenance nightmare.

You XAML code looks like it's drag & drop. Which is easy to use I guess, but I'd urge you to [abandon the visual editor](http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/03/24/disable-the-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio/) and code your XAML "by hand".

---

A quick solution for now: look at the code that you repeat over and over, i.e. most of this:

```
        int k = 0;
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Height = 28;
        label.Width = 100;
        label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        label.Content = str[j];
        dr[k] = label.Content;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        location += 34;
```

Once you start to copy-paste code and simply change one or two things, you know that's a sign you need to move it to a method that will accept the necessary parameters.

Comment: you know what sir. . 
I love u :) thanks and thanks alot for the helpful guideline and review. 
I will improve it in sha ALLAH :) 
any good book or tutorial on databinding that u recommend please?Eager to learn.